# How to make connection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase

How to connect a argis, sde version through stand alone python script. SDE.Mapping is child version of SDE.Default and I want to make child version of SDE.Mapping . I am using direct sde services

[image]

Comment: This looks promising: [Change Version (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000p5000000)

Comment: ...or [Create Version (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Create_Version/0017000000p6000000/)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Amarinel, this works.

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

# Set local variables
inWorkspace = "Q:\\NHD project\\Connection to Oracle.sde"
inFeatures = "Q:\\NHD project\\Connection to Oracle.sde\\ARCFM.Landbase\\ARCFM.Towns"
outFeatures = "Q:\\NHD project\\Towns\\towns.shp"
tempLayer = "townsLayer"
```